# ReactJS - prevent re-render children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have parent React component with 3 children, like this:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
     return (<div>
         <C1/>
         <C2/>
         <C3/>
       </div>)
   }
})
```

I am trying to be able to change children's position based on current parent state. So in different cases I need to return **C1,C3,C2** or **C3,C2,C1**, etc.
**But I want to this without re-render the children.** 
I am trying to use **shouldComponentUpdate** on each of the children but its gets called for the components that didn't change their position within parent's render method.
So if initially return **C1, C2, C3** then **C2, C1, C3** then **shouldComponentUpdate** gets called for **C3** but not for **C1** or **C2** so in this case I can return false inside C3 and prevent re-render but I don't understand why shouldComponentUpdate is not called for the children that did change their position.

Any suggestions? thank you.

Comment: How are you implementing `shouldComponentUpdate`? Remember, `shouldComponentUpdate` is a function that should tell React *when* to update, not just return `true` or `false`.

Comment: I don't have an implementation for it yet because first I try at least to get shouldComponent called inside children every time the parent re-renders them.

Comment: Let's take a step back and re-evaluate your approach.  Are these children all an instance of the same component class?  If so, wouldn't you just need to pass different props to them, causing them to effectively swap positions?

Comment: @ValeriuMazare: If you don't have an implementation for it, then how can you expect `shouldComponentUpdate` to be called? :) I'm just asking for the function you assigned to `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan, Maybe I wasn't clear enought but the thing I try to achieve now is to make sure **shouldComponentUpdate** gets called inside every children every time their parent renders them. 
I expect it to be called because it should get called implicitly by React.

Comment: @MichaelParker, no, they are different instances. I declare them like:
`var C1 = React.createClass....`
`var C2 = React.createClass....`....

Comment: @ValeriuMazare - Sure, but that wasn't what I was asking.  I want to know if they are all an instance of the same class.  For example, if your parent component was a `<TodoList/>`, then each of the children would be a `<Todo/>`.  Is this the case?

Comment: @MichaelParker
They are actually 3 different things. Lets say : one of them is a `TodoList`, another is a `PhotoGallery`, and the third is a `ContactForm`

Comment: That does make this a bit trickier.  Do you mind if I ask why you are trying to prevent re-renders on the children?  What is the problem that you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @MichaelParker it's just expensive to re-render them since they are very nested but actually there is no need to do it because I only try to achieve a change of their positions in the DOM but nothing inside them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments.
Keyed fragments were designed to solve theses kind of problem ;)